# d3.js force directed graph: How to make node size depends on the value of the links?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I have this kind of data:

```js
var nodes = [
{
    "id": "A",
    "label": "Data A",
    "group": "0",
    "level": "0"
}, {
    "id": "B",
    "label": "Data B",
    "group": "1",
    "level": "1"
},
// etc //
]

var links = [
{
    "source": "A",
    "target": "B",
"strength": "0.5",
    "value": "276"
}, {
    "source": "A",
    "target": "C",
"strength": "0.5",
"value": "866"
},
// etc //
]
```

I've been trying to set the nodes radius size according to the `value` from the links that have said node as its `target`.

So for example, node B should have its size according to the value of 276 (the link that have node B as its target).

This what I use:

```js
var nodeElements = g.append("g") 
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(node,link){
          var radius = 12;
          if (node.level == 0) radius = radius * 2; // Setting up the main node as bigger than others

          node.weight = link.filter(function(link) {
             if (link.target.index == node.index){
               var linkValue = link.value;
               if (linkValue > 500) ? (radius = 12) : (radius = 6);
             }
          });

          return radius;
      })
    .attr("fill", getNodeColor)
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .on('mouseover', selectNode)
```

That doesn't seem to work though. Says it doesn't recognize the `link.filter`, something [I've taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43906810/651170). I'm using d3.js v4.

Tried looking up for clues but still got no hints. Any ideas?

Comment: The function that sets the "r" attr is incorrect. The arguments to the anonymous function are "current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes)". See https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that need to change, but first you should understand that you are not automatically adding `links` to the node's data.

So the purpose of the filter statement seems to be to find the corresponding link in that array, based on index.
There is no `link` variable passed into the outer function, but instead you should be searching through the `links` array defined above for one link that has target with the node's id.

If you only need one link, and not all of them, use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). But `filter` and `find` work the same way - the anonymous function defined is called on each item in the array. `find` stops at the first found object, while `filter` returns all matches.

```
.attr("r", function(dat, index, n) {
    var linkItem = links.find(function(link) {
        return link.target == dat.id;
    });
    var radius = 12;
    // linkItem would be undefined if the item was not found in the links
    if (linkItem && linkItem.value > 500) {
        radius = 12;
    } else {
        radius = 6;
    }

    // you should double the radius towards the end,
    // so that radius doesn't get overwritten
    if (dat.level === 0) {
        radius = 2 * radius;
    }

    return radius;
})
```