# Trying to do a dynamic radius in d3.js and getting error: TypeError: size is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm following the post here:
[D3 Node radius depends on number of links : weight property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43906686/d3-node-radius-depends-on-number-of-links-weight-property) to dynamically set the size of a node in my graph.

I followed the StackOverflow link to get the dynamic weight dependent on degree like this:

```
node.append("circle")
.attr("r", function(d) {
   d.weight = links.filter(function(l) {
     return l.source.index == d.index || l.target.index == d.index
   }).size();
   var minRadius = 10;
   return minRadius + (d.weight * 2);
 });
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: links.filter(...).size is not a function
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Here is my whole script:

```
d3.dsv(",", "board_games.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    source: d.source,
    target: d.target,
    value: +d.value
  }
}).then(function(data) {

  var links = data;

  var nodes = {};

  // compute the distinct nodes from the links.
  links.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
  });

  var width = 1200,
      height = 700;

  var force = d3.forceSimulation()
      .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(100))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .force("x", d3.forceX())
      .force("y", d3.forceY())
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-250))
      .alphaTarget(1)
      .on("tick", tick);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // add the links
  var path = svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; });

  // define the nodes
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
         d.weight = links.filter(function(l) {
           return l.source.index == d.index || l.target.index == d.index
         }).size();
         d.weight = 5;
         var minRadius = 10;
         return minRadius + (d.weight * 2);
       });

    // add the curvy lines
  function tick() {
      path.attr("d", function(d) {
          var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
              dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
              dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
          return "M" +
              d.source.x + "," +
              d.source.y + "A" +
              dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
              d.target.x + "," +
              d.target.y;
      });

      node.attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });
  };

  function dragstarted(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
  };

  function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
  };

  function dragended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);
      if (d.fixed == true) {
          d.fx = d.x;
          d.fy = d.y;
      }
      else {
          d.fx = null;
          d.fy = null;
      }
  };

}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In the example stack overflow post, it was using size() I'm not sure how that worked, but I used length instead and it is working.

```
node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
         d.weight = links.filter(function(l) {
           return l.source.index == d.index || l.target.index == d.index
         }).length;
         console.log("d weight", d.weight)
         var minRadius = 10;
         return minRadius + (d.weight * 2);
       });
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `attr("r")` function, you are doing `d.weight = 5;` *after* computing it dynamically, which will set **every node** to a weight of 5. You can remove that line to get the computed weight working:

```
  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
         d.weight = links.filter(function(l) {
           return l.source.index == d.index || l.target.index == d.index
         }).size();
         var minRadius = 10;
         return minRadius + (d.weight * 2);
       });
```

Comment: I had accidentally left that line in when testing, but after removing that, I'm still getting the same error mentioned in the original post (which is now updated)